# Compile C++ program for iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, static-libraries, objective-c++

Here I have a program that is written in C++ and the program communicates with outside world using the standard input and standard output. (std::cin and std::cout) I want to change the source of this program and compile it for iOS. My question is, is it possible to compile an static library in Xcode as Objective C++ and then use the library in a Objective C project?

Comment: It depends if you expose C++ objects in that static library.  You can implement the library in Objective-C++ and only expose Objective-C objects and that will work fine.

Comment: @trojanfoe I haven't had success doing it. let's keep it simple, If I have a cocoa touch static library with two files in it: 1- test.cpp and 2- test.h and the test.cpp has only one function like printSomething() that prints a line using the std::cout can I compile this as objective C++ and use it in another objective C project? I did as mentioned but I get errors like iostream.h not being found.

Comment: You need to ensure that test.h doesn't expose anything C++ if Objective-C is including that file.  This includes giving `printSomething()` C-linkage (using `extern "C" { ... }`).

Comment: OP explicitly states "is it possible to compile an static library in Xcode as **Objective C++**"